# R Snow Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : one node produced an error: cannot open the connection

Tags: r, lapply

I have several months of successful experience using SNOW on three host cluster in which I source proprietary functions using clusterEvalQ(cl, source('blah')).  Old source code works fine. In adding new features, I created new proprietary method files and found some files would not source from master.  The only difference between files that I am aware of is the file name.  Is it possible some file names work and some do not?  Do you know of a way to determine what is actually failing so we can find a workaround?

utils_grid.r was created from ta.r using cp command. "ta.r" works, "utils_grid.r" does not.

$ `diff utils_grid.r ta.r` 
$

> -rwxrwxrwx. 1 tim developers 6.2K Jan 22 10:12 utils_grid.r*
>   -rwxrwxrwx. 1 tim developers 6.2K Sep 12 14:06 ta.r*

```
clusterEvalQ(cl,source(file="/home/mslade/exp/trunk/R/rsrc/AlphaRex/utils_grid.r"))
```

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :    one node
>   produced an error: cannot open the connection

```
clusterEvalQ(cl,source("/home/mslade/exp/trunk/R/rsrc/AlphaRex/ta.r",verbose=F,echo=T))
```

> [[1]] [[1]]$value function (data, topn = 1, keepn = 1, dirMaxMin =
>   TRUE)  {
>       temp = coredata(data)
>       for (i in 1:nrow(temp)) {
>           x = temp[i, ]
>           o = sort.list(x, na.last = TRUE, decreasing = dirMaxMin)
>           index = which(!is.na(x))
>           x[] = NA
>           if (len(index) > 0) {
>               n = min(topn, len(index))
>               x[o[1:n]] = 1
>               if (i >= 2) { . . . (remainder omitted)
>
> R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30) Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
>   (64-bit)
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
>   LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8     [7] LC_PAPER=C 
>   LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
>   LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices
>   utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] lmtest_0.9-30      abind_1.4-0
>   snow_0.3-9         tseries_0.10-28    quadprog_1.5-4     ipred_0.8-13 
>   prodlim_1.3.1      KernSmooth_2.23-7   [9] nnet_7.3-1
>   mlbench_2.1-0      MASS_7.3-17        randomForest_4.6-6 ellipse_0.3-7
>   mclust_3.4.11      pvclust_1.2-2      maptree_1.4-6      [17]
>   rpart_3.1-52       class_7.3-3        cluster_1.14.2     RTAQ_0.2
>   timeDate_2160.97   Hmisc_3.9-3        survival_2.36-12
>   lattice_0.20-6     [25] Romd_0.1.15        statUtils_0.1.8
>   Rcpp_0.9.10        quantmod_0.3-17    TTR_0.21-1
>   Defaults_1.1-1     xts_0.8-6          hydroGOF_0.3-4     [33]
>   zoo_1.7-7          MethComp_1.15      nlme_3.1-103
>   SDMTools_1.1-12    rmongodb_1.0.3     RMongo_0.0.21      RUnit_0.4.26 
>   rJava_0.9-3        [41] xtable_1.7-0       moments_0.13
>   gtools_2.6.2       rjson_0.2.8        RMySQL_0.9-3       DBI_0.2-5
>   RODBC_1.3-5
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] automap_1.0-12
>   e1071_1.6      grid_2.15.0    gstat_1.0-13   hydroTSM_0.3-5 sp_0.9-99 
>   tools_2.15.0

Comment: does it work when you run it on a single node?

Comment: What does the script do? Does it interact with a database by any chance?